# How can I tell which GNOME Shell extensions are local packages?

Tags: gnome-shell

I have installed GNOME Shell extensions from two sources:

- my distribution repository (i.e. installed as a local package)
- https://extensions.gnome.org

Sometimes I get prompted with an upgrade from extensions.gnome.org, but I can't tell what the original state of the extension was (so I can decide whether to get the upgrade, switch source, etc).

How can I see which source an extension came from?

Answer (score 1):

The prompt to upgrade is coming from your browser's "GNOME Shell integration" plugin. If you follow the prompt you will be taken to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ where all your extensions (from both sources) will be listed.

Extensions from the website have a red "X" button, indicating they can be uninstalled. Local packages cannot be uninstalled by "GNOME Shell integration", so they don't get an X.

[image: Website-sourced extensions have a red X indicating they can be uninstalled]

In Debian-based distributions, most extensions are found in individual packages `gnome-shell-extension-X` or `gnome-shell-extensions-X`. Other distributions may follow a similar convention.

The exception is the package [gnome-shell-extensions](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/gnome-shell-extensions) (no suffix). This package contains the set of "official" extensions from GNOME. These are likely the ones installed as local packages.

Comment: Package-based extensions are also identified by “System extension” under their name, as seen in your screenshot.

Comment: I... I can't believe it